# How do I fire my Lasers?

Tags: star-command

I've just acquired some laser cannons for my ship, but when I try to fire them, I'm faced with a mini-game to lock on to my target.

But I have no real idea how I should play this mini game, and the game itself seems to provide no instructions.

**How do I complete the laser cannon mini game?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minigame for firing the Laser Cannons is basically a timing/reflexes challenge.

There are three yellow rings, each with a small red ring on the top. Once you start the minigame, a red dot (one per yellow ring) will begin to circle the yellow ring it's located on at varying speeds. Your objective is to tap each yellow ring just as the red dot passes through the red ring. Be careful to take note of which red dots are faster than others, as you'll tap them in order of fastest to slowest. Thankfully, you'll never need to simultaneously fire more than one ring at a time. For each success, a laser cannon is fired, doing around 30 points of damage. Do all three successfully and you'll deal around 90 points of damage.

Answer (score 1):

The laser minigame is a matter of timing. The red circles are where you tap once the the little traveling yellow ball enters the yellow circle. There are three of them, and the idea is to tap them in the correct order, at the right time, since they will never have to be tapped at the same time.

Note that the timing will be different each time you fire; sometimes its left to right, sometimes the opposite, or entirely different. Each one you successfully complete is one "hit", and the cannon will fire once per hit.